# stylesheet link rel and shortcut icon link rel cannot co-exist

Tags: html, css

I have a problem trying to add a favicon and stylesheet to my personal website i'm trying to build. This is what i have at the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
      PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Super Chilun's Portfolio</title>
<link rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="myicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

The favicon part loads fine, but I cannot load the external mystyle.css file (just a few lines for now)

```
hr {color:sienna;}
p {margin-left:20px;}
body {background-image:url("mybackground.png");}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The path to your stylesheet is correct?

Comment: check the path of the stylehseet, it is showing up in browser source, so must be file path error

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses - the stylesheet is in the same location of my html file - index.html...

Answer (score 1):

For html external style-sheets...if not, html5, `type="text/css"` is an important attribute to identify the content type.

try adding it and it should work, if not, check the path to the `css` file...

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
<!--__^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^__this part-->
```

Comment: To clarify, if the **doctype of the page** is not HTML5 (i.e. "<!doctype html>") then you should add the type attribute (in addition to the rel) as described above.

Comment: Hi; I've tried specifying the link type as you suggested, but the outcome is still the same. The css file is in the same location as my index.html file

Comment: @user1283674 : hi...go to the source code of your page `Ctrl` + `U` in `mozilla` and click on the stylesheet link that you have given....can you tell me if it opens from there???

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the background image file - now working fine